# CLI interface for avaya 9608G IP Phone

Tags: automation, avaya

I've a Avaya IP-Phone 9608G and I want to control it from my CLI.

Can anyone help me to know CLI interafce for avaya IP phone

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not specify what specific task you would like to achieve, I list the technologies I use for interacting with Avaya phones below. You can use them to implement CLI applications to do what your use case is screaming for.

The following interfaces you can use to interact with the Avaya phones:

1. AES/CTI Server using the CVLAN or TSAPI protocol. You can control/monitor the PBX objects with it so you can see what is happening on your desk phone or you can initiate a call, answer an incoming one, etc...

You can use the TSAPI for C programs or JTAPI for Java programs.

[TSAPI overview](https://www.devconnectprogram.com/site/global/products_resources/avaya_aura_application_enablement_services/interfaces/tsapi/overview/index.gsp)

2. AES Server using the CMAPI/DMCC protocol. With that you can register on to your desk phone. Using CMAPI/DMCC you can "pushing" your physical buttons, check what the desk phone display is currently showing, etc.

[DMCC overview](https://www.devconnectprogram.com/site/global/products_resources/avaya_aura_application_enablement_services/interfaces/dmcc/overview/index.gsp)

3. You can use the Push SDK for pushing unsolicited content to the phone's display.

[PushSDK overview](https://www.devconnectprogram.com/site/global/products_resources/avaya_ip_deskphones/interfaces/push_api/overview/index.gsp)

Comment: I would like to automate the calls for two avaya IP phones 9608G via PBX using python based robotframework for which do we have any pre existence library or any interface?? As i have automated calls for CISCO 7940 IP phone using Telnet interface

Comment: Any suggestions please